# Ubuntu 18.04 closing laptop lid stops wi-fi connection

Tags: ubuntu, power-management

I have an  issue with Ubuntu 18.04 and closing the lid of the laptop.
rather with loosing internet connection when the lid is closed.
 I noticed that machine does not even respond to ping when the lid is closed.
I've setup Power manager to 'ignore' closed lid. I reconfigured logind.conf but it did not have an effect.

Could someone please advice how to keep wi-fi connection when the lid is closed?
 Note:I did not have the issue with 16.04
 Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Ive had the same issue before.  This is an easy fix:

Edit `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf` with your editor of choice. This will require `sudo`.

Find the following line:

```
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 2
```

Change the 2 to a 3

Save the file and exit.

After saving type:

```
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

Comment: Hi Keltari. Thanks for suggestion.
I checked the file and the value was already 3.
Any other suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: @susik try changing it to 2 and test.

Comment: Both values did not work for me

Comment: While this is different from https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently

Answer (score 2):

Try https://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

It worked for me on 20.04LTS

Comment: There is a new entry there called HandleLidSwitchExternalPower. I had to set this one to "ignore". The other solutions did not work. I had this for Ubuntu 23.10 as well as Debian 12/Bookworm.